# Windows 7 redirect sound from to speakers to just one speaker

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

I have a pc with windows 7 installed and a speaker connected at the rear (one connection two speakers). The problem is that the right speaker does not receive signal beacause a problem with the cable. So when  I play an audio i can't hear anything that comes from the right side. Is there any way to configure the pc to send all the audio signal to the left speaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn a speaker into a mono speaker (left channel only) by adding a stereo to mono plug to the cable. You can buy these at an electronic store.

Alternatively you may be able to configure your soundcard to output everything in mono, but this is something that not every soundcard supports.

Comment: thakns, when first i go to my local store they didn't say i can buy a plug. I had to go  to further to take one of this and works perfect.